# SQL Server - sync two tables with same structure

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables that created with same structure and data type. Some values are added in `Table1` and some values are added in `Table2`. Now, I like to somehow INSERT both tables (sync them) with the values they are missing. I will use Col1 for comparison of the two tables.  Please see below demonstration of the result I hope to get.

**Table1**:

```
Col1 Col2
v1   1
v2   2
v3   3
v6   6
```

**Table2**:

```
Col1 Col2
v1   1
v4   4
v5   5
```

Result for Table1 or Table2 will be

```
v1   1
v2   2
v3   3
v4   4
v5   5
v6   6
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way, inserting rows from Table2 that don't already exist in Table1;

```
INSERT INTO Table1
  SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table2 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Table1 
    WHERE Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
  );
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30bac/4).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM
    Table2 t2
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE
    t1.Col1 IS NULL
GO

INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Col1 = t1.Col1
WHERE
    t2.Col1 IS NULL
GO
```